# retriev data from controller using ajax

Tags: codeigniter

below code returns me blank in ajax response please help me
    when i check my controller it also gives me blank.
    Can you please check the code below to find out the reason of problem

here is my ajax code:

```
window.onload = function() {
     $.ajax({
        type:'json',
        url:"http://localhost/myapne/admin/adminMenu/getMsg",

        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
           // PrintSms(data);
        },
          error: function(error){
      console.log(error);   
                    }
    });
```

}

here is my controller:

```
class AdminMenu extends CI_Controller{
function getMsg(){

    $this->load->model('adminGetModel');
    $data = $this->adminGetModel->getSms();
    return array("status"=>"success","rows"=>$data);
}
```

}

here is my model:

```
class AdminGetModel extends CI_Model{

function getSms(){
//        $a = $count*10;
//        $b = $a + 10;
    $this->load->database();
       $query = $this->db->get('tblsms');
       $rows = array(); //will hold all results

    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
   {    
    $rows[] = $row; //add the fetched result to the result array;
   }

     return $rows; 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Json_encode the data and use echo instead of return:

```
echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success","rows"=>$data));
```

This will return a string. If you want to turn it back into an object, you will then have to use `JSON.parse()` (or `$.parseJSON` if you're using jquery) in your ajax success handler.